# Office.EventType.ItemChanged not fired

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

For an Outlook Addin, I am registering the [Office.EventType.ItemChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.eventtype) event like this:

```
Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, this.updateAndNotifyCurrentMessageHandlers);
```

With the task pane pinned open the event fires when I select another email.
However, if the message in the inbox is an 'Outlook calendar invitation' or an 'undelivered notification' the event does not fire.

Why?

Here the manifest:
[Manifest](https://pastebin.com/KqQFngwh)

Comment: What is listed in your manifest?

Comment: Manifest is here: https://pastebin.com/KqQFngwh

Comment: On which Outlook platform are you seeing this issue?

Comment: Platform: https://outlook.office.com/mail

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point.This issue is duplicate of https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1869 ..